# Is there a way to tell the user that there's no internet connection when they press submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming there is no internet connection, of course. Like a jQuery method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would try to make HEAD requests (no content downloaded) to a few servers you know are online. They will automatically fail if there is no network (no need to set a timeout).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    error: function() {
        alert('world is gone !');
    }
});
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/window.html) (unplug your network to test)

Comment: This is actually very nice. You don't have to do additional work on your server logic. Here, have a +1 :)

Comment: Note that the server must allow cross domain queries or be the origin one.

Comment: Hmm, clever, but I don't think this is necessary. Checking `navigator.onLine` should be sufficient -- see my answer.

Comment: and what happen if google does not be accessible?

Comment: @afshin ... the WORLD IS GONE!

Comment: I'm not joking for sample in my country google is not accessible for 4 days until now

Comment: Generally, the most interesting is to check the server you would access. "No network" isn't really much more interesting than "No route to the important server".

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with ajax requests, you can catch `timeout` error - see `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` in [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) reference.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, yes. Before the actual submission, you can have an `ajax` call try to connect to a simple lightweight service on your site just to check if it is reachable.

If the call fails, you can assume there's no connection.

Answer (score 0):

With help of failed XHR requests you can determine the connection. 
Retry few times , if the request doesnot go through, alert and fail gracefully.

I can use this function which I got from http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2008/06/17/publish-subscribe-with-jquery/

```
$.networkDetection = function(url,interval){
    var url = url;
    var interval = interval;
    online = false;
    this.StartPolling = function(){
        this.StopPolling();
        this.timer = setInterval(poll, interval);
    };
    this.StopPolling = function(){
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    };
    this.setPollInterval= function(i) {
        interval = i;
    };
    this.getOnlineStatus = function(){
        return online;
    };
    function poll() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "text",
            error: function(){
                online = false;
                $(document).trigger('status.networkDetection',[false]);
            },
            success: function(){
                online = true;
                $(document).trigger('status.networkDetection',[true]);
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it is to send your form using AJAX. Then you'll have a handler that will tell you that it wasn't able to connect to the server and you can save the data and inform the user that the server is not available. It doesn't really matter whether the problem is your internet connection or the server may be down.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
  alert('online');
} else {
  alert('offline');
}
```

Comment: That property is not reliable across browsers http://ejohn.org/blog/offline-events/

Comment: @JuanMendes ah, So others can learn of this, I will not delete my down voted answer :) Also, I should have read this part that talks about browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Regardless of the accuracy of the answer, you should always explain your code and why we should use it (often a sentence or two is enough.)